# mongorestore only one field of a document

Tags: performance, mongodb

i'm trying to restore my users :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  created_at: Date,
  preferences: String
}
```

I don't know why but `created_at` field from my users all reseted. So i need to use my `.bson` backup file to restore this field but i need to only edit `created_at` field.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Import your user data (.bson) to other temporary collection and then use [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) to update documents created_at keys.